# Search function ignoring diacritics

Tags: keyboard, search

The ubuntu search function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> searches wonderfully fast (since 13.10 or 14.04 or so).

But, it considers `e é è ê ē ­ë` all as different characters. I have PDF files named after their author, who may be French (`e` vs. `ë é è ê`, `c` vs. `ç`), German (`o` vs. `ö`, etc.), etc.

To help me find those files faster, I'd like the search to ignore the difference between the spelling and consider `é è ê ē ­ë` the same as `e` (just like it already considers `E` and `e` the same).

Can I change this behaviour on my machine?

*Edit.* Output (after setting Language consistently) of `set | grep ^L[A,C]` is

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Now, in a folder with two files `Algebra.pdf` and `Algèbre.pdf`, the search function filters as follows

- `alge` finds both files (that's good)
- `algè` finds only `Algèbre.pdf` (that's also good)
- `algeb` finds only `Algebra.pdf` (that's not good), in particular
  `algebre` doesn't find anything (that's not good)

Comment: Yes, you can, but... ;)  Can you provide the output to `set | grep ^L[A,C]` (in your question, please)

Comment: @Fabby I've updated the question with the output.

Comment: OK, first set everything to the same locale.  You've probably got `English` as first language in `System Settings` - `Language Suport` instead of `English (United Kingdom)`. Change that and then run the `grep` again and see if they're all the same now.

Comment: @Fabby Done, now they're all `en_GB`.

Comment: Chat? AskUbuntu General Room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that you have only one language and locality defined in your user profile, you can already see that `en_GB` has a different [collating sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collating_sequence) then `en_US`.

If you're familiar with database technology, what we'll be accomplishing is something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM tPerson WHERE Name LIKE "helen%"
Name
----
Helen
Hélène
Helena
...
```

I propose the following two possibilities:

1. Change the current language (`en_GB`) to include the diacritics of both `fr_FR` and `de_DE`
2. Create a new language (Let's call this one `eu_EU`) that is based on the language that contains the most diacritics that includes the other ones.

Advantages (by number) :

1. Less work to create a new language
2. Less possibilities of an Ubuntu upgrade breaking your work

Disadvantages (by number) :

1. Keep good back-up copies and restore them when an Ubuntu update changes `en_GB`
2. None that I can see.

Comment: Oh, and if the answer is useful, there's this little grey check-mark above the 0 that needs to be turned to green ;-) and that diacritical ^ is also begging to be pushed!  >:)

Comment: You did it???  And it works?  Congratulations!  ;-)